# Scaling pipelines maintenance effort

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, github-actions

In modern system often we work with many microservices that are stored in different repos and have own pipelines.

In my case 90% of microservices use the same technology and have the same project structure so it means there is a lot of duplication in the pipelines.

In every pipeline we have docker images, helm, and the same steps in the pipeline (run unit tests, run integration tests, build image, publish image, create helm package, etc.)

Such approach causes that for example when we want to upgrade a helm to newer version or add some new steps in the pipeline, we must repeat the same work N times in different repos.

I was wondering if there is some way to avoid work of repeating the same steps in different repos.

I would need something like this: if I introduce a new change first it is introduced in one repo and if it is working fine then I have possibility to apply the change automatically to all other repos. Any ideas about it? Does it make sense if yes how to achieve it?

Comment: If you're asking about GitHub Actions, then the answer is "reusable workflows". If you're asking in general, then this is probably not a good question for SO.

Comment: Yes reusable workflows is a good idea I think, I will try it.